# Exponents with Quadratic Equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've been working at this problem for a while and I'm having troubled, with the exponents.

[image]

I would appreciate if someone could teach me how to solve this for an exam tomorrow, this is one of few problems that I struggle with thanks in advance, I am solving for x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using hit and trial for small numbers you can see that $x=2$ is a root , hence 
$$ 4x^2(x-2)-9(x-2)=0$$

and then

$$(4x^2-9)(x-2)=0$$

$$(2x-3)(2x+3)(x-2)=0$$

Roots are $x = -1.5 , 1.5$ and $2 $

Answer (score 1):

Preface: I'm assuming that because this is a high school question, one of the roots will be an integer.

Because it is easier to deal with smaller coefficients, the first thing you ought to do is to reduce the coefficients. In our example, we can't reduce the coefficients any further, so we move onto the next step.

The next step is to find a root. Here, you will need to try factors of the constant term. So that would be $1,2,3,6,9,18$. Sub the values for $x$ and hope that the equation will yield $0$. If it does, you have found yourself a root. In this case, $2$ is a root.
So you can write $$4x^3-8x^2-9x+18=(x-2)(ax^2+bx+c)=0$$ where $a,b,c$ are to be found.

But they can easily be found by comparing coefficients to be $a=4,b=0,c=-9$. So we have $$4x^3-8x^2-9x+18=(x-2)(ax^2+bx+c)=(x-2)(4x^2-9)=0$$

Finally, you can solve the quadratic equation (sometimes you need to use the quadratic formula) to get the final answer.

Answer (score 0):

One technique to solve these kinds of questions is to "guess" and then simplify. Let me demonstrate for this example and see if you recognize the principle.

We could just do uneducated guesses, i.e. try with $x = 0$, $x = 1$, etc. I think it's reasonable to test for 0, 1, 2, 3 and -1, -2, -3. (In this case, a more educated guess is $x = 2$, since we have the "pairs 4, 8 and 9, 18")

Anyway, you somehow deduce that $x = 2$ IS a solution to the equation. Now we can divide the equation by $(x - 2)$. This implies that we end up with a quadratic equation, which is easy to solve.

In this example, the division yields $4x^2-9$ since $(x - 2)(4x^2-9)=(4x^3-8x^2-9x+18)$

Continuing, solving the equation $4x^2-9=0$ yields the solutions $x=\pm\frac{3}{2}$ (by conjugacy).

Hence, we have that the solutions are $x = 2$, $x=\frac{3}{2}$, or $x=-\frac{3}{2}$.

Personally, I prefer to rewrite the equation as:
$$
(4x^3-8x^2-9x+18)=(x - 2)\left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)\left(x+\frac{3}{2}\right) = 0,
$$
once I'm "done", since this exposes the solutions very clearly.